# drupal 7..mails are not being sent on localhost

Tags: drupal-7, sendmail

i am using drupal 7 to build my new site. Web server i am using is wamp. Now creating new account takes a lot of time and at the end gives a list of errors. I am new to drupal so cant understand how to handle these errors. error page is as under

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry. in DefaultMailSystem->mail() (line 77 of C:\xampp\htdocs\attempt2\modules\system\system.mail.inc).
Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists

how to solve it?
anyone.............?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have administrator access to the server?

It sounds like the SMTP settings need to be adjusted on the server. If this is a shared Windows host, you may need to configure Drupal to use an external SMTP server, not localhost.

If you have administrative control of the server, first, make sure SMTP is running in "Services", then check the SMTP configuration in IIS>

Comment: Start > Run > Services.msc
look for "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol"

Comment: Select the service and click "Start", or right-click the service and click "Start Service"

Comment: You probably need to install the Windows component.
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: i am using the xampp server now, and installed smtp auth module for drupal7 as well but still no progress.. \n getting the following error \n Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, using gmail smtp one must need openssl enabled.
i made it and solved the problem.
i also used smtp authentication support module of drupal.

thanks canutsen for your help